# Hardware Issue Preventing Boot

Tags: boot, grub2, hardware, cpu, motherboard

I have a 10 year old barebones tower that's only ever ran Ubuntu. Recently this is what appears prior to GRUB menu (I had multiple distros). I now can't get into the GRUB menu and it doesn't boot at although it does turn on. It used to 'beep' physically before I got to the OS menu but not anymore. Manufacturer is American Megatrends and I think those manufacturers computers do that. I just get this pixel-ly screen and nothing responds. Don't even see caps lock toggle.

- Nothing to do with display ports, all checked
- No recent heavy shocks, falls
- One fan does not work but that's not worked for a long time. Could be an issue as it used to work hard while I was doing my development
- Processor is/was Intel Core i5-2320 3Ghz. Recently had upgrade the RAM to total 12GB DDR3

My main question is what's the best way to check for broken components and fix them. Is it my motherboard? Is it my processor? Any obvious things to check so I can just replace as little as possible to get it working again.

[image: Screen after turning on the computer]

Comment: Nothing you can do in Ubuntu is going to solve a hardware problem and if you can't get to the BIOS menu or load a live operating system, you won't be able to use Ubuntu to diagnose the issue either. My advice? Remove everything that isn't essential to the system booting. CPU and one stick of RAM. Test each RAM module one at a time. If the system still can't get you to a BIOS menu then the motherboard or CPU is probably dead/dying

Comment: Thanks for the comment. It still didn't do anything so time to visit an expert and bring it in.

Comment: Had same issue in computer I fixed about 1 year ago. Bad video card.

Comment: I do wonder if David’s spot on and this might be graphics card - especially as it beeps and you get some display, albeit distorted. Is there a video output direct from the mobo? Some do -  if you can exclude the graphics card that might help troubleshooting. Also, if you have an old graphics card you can put in instead - that might save you a trip to a shop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out it was the CPU. Thanks to all comments.